# Impact of importing unused modules in Vue.js on performance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js component where I've imported a module, specifically useI18n from "vue-i18n", but I realized that I'm not using it anywhere in the component. I'm concerned about the potential impact on performance, especially in terms of bundle size and load times.

- Does importing a module that is not used in the component affect the performance of that specific component?
- How does it contribute to the overall bundle size, and can it impact the initial load times of the application?
- Are there best practices for handling unused imports in Vue.js to optimize performance?

I've considered the potential impact of importing the module useI18n from "vue-i18n" without using it in my Vue.js component. However, I'm unsure about the specific performance implications.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can build your applicaton with or without the module and measure performance. [Vue Dev Tools browser plugin](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?pli=1) can help. If you can't measure or notice then the impact is probably not an issue. People are pushing full-video ads to browsers. A couple kilobytes for an unused module won't shatter your user's experience I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Peter Krebs comment.

Personnaly, depending of using `vue-cli` or `vite` to create the bundle, I always look at the report created with the following methods :

**vue-cli**

In `package.json`, with the target used to create your component bundle (here called `lib` for the sample), add the `--report` flag : it will generate `report.html` to help analyze bundle content (documentation [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build)).

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "lib": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name mycomponent ./src/index.js --report",
}
...
```

**vite**

Install the [`rollup-plugin-visualizer`](https://github.com/btd/rollup-plugin-visualizer) npm package

In vite.config.js, declare the import, add it to the plugins field in returned config and enjoy the result opening the file declared in the `filename` field.

```js
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer'

const plugins = [visualizer({
    filename: 'dist/report.html'
})]
```